# is there any way to connect and get mails from office 365 on iphone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, email, ios5, office365

i wanna make my own application to reach my mails. i'm using office 365 mail exchange, and i really hate outlook webmail. how can i connect and get my mails from there on iphone, any idea? i dont have any idea about this. is this way must be http post or any api in there ?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Not sure how viable this is, but worth checking out. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=c3342fb3-fbcc-4127-becf-872c746840e1

Comment: i just looked at there, i found nothing. All they know is trying to sell something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the mail app. It supports Exchange Active Sync natively.
http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/cc825479.aspx#Apple

If you really want to code it, a good start is Exchange Web Services:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg194011(v=exchg.140).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft released a preview of Office 365 APIs with REST services for Email, Calendar and Contacts. 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605896(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605896%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

The authorization is OAuth2 based, you can download their VS 2013 extension and there is code there that shows how to connect to exchange using what They call multi-resource refresh tokens:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7e947621-ef93-4de7-93d3-d796c43ba34f

The sample also contains code that shows how to query for email, contacts, etc... once you have received your access token.